# Installing Tensorflow on macOS on an Arm MBP

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

When attempting to install tensorflow on an ARM M1 MacBookPro, I am seeing the following issues:

```
% pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

After searching around, I found a package called [tensorflow-macos](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-macos/) which produces the following issues:

```
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
    error: Command "gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/thing/dev/SOTAMoon/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers -std=c99" failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/81/20d5d994c91ed8347efda90d32c396ea28254fd8eb9e071e28ee5700ffd5/h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=1e2516f190652beedcb8c7acfa1c6fa92d99b42331cbef5e5c7ec2d65b0fc3c2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/h5py/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/thing/dev/SOTAMoon/venv/bin/python3 /private/var/folders/8k/z291bhgd5gs06tp9b4j6_bb40000gn/T/pip-standalone-pip-8qa87uy0/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/8k/z291bhgd5gs06tp9b4j6_bb40000gn/T/pip-build-env-bxy_nyoo/normal --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'numpy==1.12; python_version == "3.6"' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version >= "3.9"' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version == "3.7"' pkgconfig 'Cython>=0.29; python_version < "3.8"' 'Cython>=0.29.14; python_version >= "3.8"' 'numpy==1.17.5; python_version == "3.8"' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement h5py~=3.1.0 (from tensorflow-macos) (from versions: 2.2.1, 2.3.0b1, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0b1, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.7.0rc2, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0, 2.10.0, 3.0.0rc1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for h5py~=3.1.0
```

Unfortunately I couldn't work out a solution to the 'faltivec' issue. I also found a [tensorflow package made by Apple](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) that seems specifically geared for M1's, however going by [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-on-the-m1-mac-410bb36b776) produces the following issues:

```
% pip install --upgrade --force --no-dependencies https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_addons_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
ERROR: tensorflow_addons_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

After this, I am a bit stuck. I have upgraded pip to `21.1.3`, and my python version is `Python 3.9.6`.

Comment: Follow the instructions mentioned in the [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) to install Tenosrflow. If you are facing version incompatibility, build Tensorflow from source by following the instructions mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#macos_1). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### Tensorflow-macos and Tensorflow-metal Install

Currently, to harness the M1 GPU you need to install `Tensorflow-macos` and `TensorFlow-metal` as opposed to `Tensorflow`, the install steps are detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/), they can be summarized as follows using mini-forge:

```
conda create -n tf python=3.8 -y
conda activate tf
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps -y
# Navigate the issue with conda environments
# built against pre-macOS 11 SDK use (Just in case)
# this solves the Intel / M1 install issues:
SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 pip install tensorflow-macos 
SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 pip install tensorflow-metal
```

to test all is well we can run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PYCMD=$(cat <<EOF
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.list_physical_devices()
with tf.device('/GPU'):
  a = tf.random.normal(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.float32)
  b = tf.nn.relu(a)

print(a)
print(b)

EOF
)

python3 -c "$PYCMD" 2>/dev/null
```

the expected output for my test machine:

```
>./val.sh
Metal device set to: Apple M1

systemMemory: 16.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 5.33 GB

tf.Tensor([-0.4044231   0.08157467], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.         0.08157467], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

ok, everything is (assumed) to be working...

#### Side-Note: Package Install Issues:

One thing to note is that that packages that rely on `tensorflow` will try to install `tensorflow` as they will likely not have an explicit dependency on `tensorflow-macos` or `tensorflow-metal`.

When you install `tensorflow` dependent packages or code you'll likely have to review the `requirements.txt file` before running:

```
python3 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The `requirements.txt` will try to install the `tensorflow` package, not the `tensorflow-macosx` or `tensorflow-metal` packages which will result in a host of issues if you run the `requirements.txt` file unchanged. That and explicit versions of packages `==` which can also cause problems.

Hopefully, this points you in the right direction in thinking about the hurdles involved in getting python to work with the Apple-M1 laptops using the TensorFlow metal plugin to harness the M1 GPU features.

Stay safe and well.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

you may also need:

```
brew install hdf5
export HDF5_DIR=$(brew --prefix hdf5)
```